# Restore variables in ipython

Tags: ipython, spyder

I use the options "remove all variables before execution" in Spyder, that uses the magic `%reset -sf`.

Now I would like to have the default setting back (the variables are kept in memory) but I can't (I used the Spyder reset to factory default).

Answer (score 1):

To modify the `Remove all variables before execution` you probably will need to go to `Run > Configuration per file..` and uncheck the option there for the file you are working on. The thing is that there are some default options available but also per file options which maybe are not being reset even when you do a reset to factory (those are created if you modify the config the first time you run a file).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I add to check the option "Run in console's namespace instead of an empty one" for it to work.